# Testing for Linearity and Shift-Invariance

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems

I started school a week and a half ago and we have gotten already a big chunk of material and I wanted to check if what I am currently doing is correct. Here below are the problems to work out that help us for the exam in the future. (This class is signal processing)

[image]

for part (b)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your demonstration of shift-invariance is not correct.

You time-shift the input signal by $n_0$, which is correct. But you also time-shift the sinusoidal, and this only happens if you were time-shifting the output.

The description of the system contains a signal that explicitly depends on time ($\sin(2\pi/7 n \cdots)$). In general this is a red-flag for non time-invariance.